# Filling up the rest of the slides with a dot grid pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, slideshow

Is there a way to fill up the rest of the text field of a beamer class slide with a dot grid pattern? The idea is a "frame" that gets a title name and after a line break, it fills the rest of the text field of the slide with a dot grid paper.

The dotgridfill-macro showcases what I try to say:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,t,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\dotgridfill}[1]{
    \begin{block}{#1}
    \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \y in {1,2,...,20}
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,57}
        {
          \draw[fill=black,opacity=0.3,shift={(0.25*\x cm,0.25*\y cm)}] (0,0) circle[radius=0.5pt];
        }%
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{block}
}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{Test}
        \lipsum[6]
    \end{block}
    \dotgridfill{Name}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.SE ! Could you please clarify a bit your demand ? In your post you state that you want : " a"frame" that gets a title name and after a line break, it fills the rest of the text field of the slide with a dot grid paper". However in your example, there is a block with a title and some content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposal based on you example. It uses `tikz` libraries `positioning` to find the lower right corner of the area to be filled, and `patterns.meta` to actually fill the area with dots.
You can easily modify the vertical margin between the dotted area and the lower side of the frame, as well as the dot pattern settings.

```
% arara: lwpdflatex
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,t,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,patterns.meta}

 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dotgridfill}[1]{
    \begin{block}{#1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \coordinate[above left = 5mm and \Gm@rmargin of current page.south east] (innersoutheast);
    \fill[pattern={Dots[distance=0.25cm,radius=0.5pt,xshift=1pt]},pattern color=gray] (0,0) rectangle (innersoutheast);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{block}
}
\makeatother
 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{Test}
        \lipsum[6]
    \end{block}
    \dotgridfill{Name}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]